# About reparametrization of timelike curves in $\mathbb{L}^3$ (Lorentz-Minkowski space)

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, proof-verification, mathematical-physics, semi-riemannian-geometry

I think there is something wrong with the proof this [text](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0810.3351v1.pdf) gives of **Lemma $2.1.5$**, in pages $19$ and $20$, for timelike curves. I used another function, and it seems to work. Either I'm wrong, or he is. Can someone check, please?
I'm using the convention $$\langle (x_1,y_1,z_1),(x_2,y_2,z_2) \rangle = x_1x_2+y_1y_2 - z_1z_2$$

and, just to remind, $\|(x,y,z)\| = \sqrt{|\langle (x,y,z),(x,y,z)\rangle|}$.

**My work:** We consider $\alpha: I \rightarrow \mathbb{L}^3$ a timelike curve. Fix $t_0 \in I$ and consider the function $$s(t) = \int_{t_0}^t \sqrt{- \langle \alpha ' (\xi), \alpha'(\xi) \rangle} \mathrm{d}\xi$$

Then we have $s'(t) = \sqrt{- \langle \alpha ' (t), \alpha'(t) \rangle} > 0$, then $s$ is strictly increasing, so we have an inverse $h$. Since $h(s(t)) = t$ for all $t \in I$, by differentiation, we have $$\begin{align} h'(s(t)) \cdot s'(t) &= 1 \\ h'(s(t)) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{- \langle \alpha ' (t), \alpha'(t) \rangle}}\end{align}$$

and so $h'(t) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{- \langle \alpha ' (h(t)), \alpha'(h(t)) \rangle}}$. To finish it, I just have to check that the parametrization $\alpha \circ h$ satisfies $\| (\alpha \circ h)'(t) \| = 1$. So: $$\begin{align}\| (\alpha \circ h)'(t) \| &= \| \alpha'(h(t)) \cdot h'(t) \| \\ &= \left\|\alpha'(h(t)) \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{- \langle \alpha ' (h(t)), \alpha'(h(t)) \rangle}} \right\| \\[2pt] &=\sqrt{\left|\left\langle \frac{\alpha'(h(t))}{\sqrt{- \langle \alpha ' (h(t)), \alpha'(h(t)) \rangle}}, \frac{\alpha'(h(t))}{\sqrt{- \langle \alpha ' (h(t)), \alpha'(h(t)) \rangle}} \right\rangle\right|} \\[2pt] &= \sqrt{\left| \frac{1}{-\langle \alpha'(h(t)), \alpha'(h(t))\rangle} \cdot \langle \alpha'(h(t)), \alpha'(h(t)) \rangle\right|} \\ &=\sqrt{\left| \frac{1}{-1}\right|} = 1\end{align}$$
$\hspace{15 cm}\square$

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are perfectly right.

If $s(t)$ were $-\int_{t_0}^t\langle\alpha',\alpha'\rangle$ without the square root, we would get $\frac1{\|\alpha'\|}$ for the norm of $\alpha\circ s^{-1}$ instead of $1$.

Assume that the reparametrized curve is $\beta$, so $\beta\circ s=\alpha$ for some diffeomorphism $s$ (at least locally around $t_0$). Then we have
$$\alpha'=(\beta\circ s)'=(\beta'\circ s)\cdot s'$$
consequently, $\|\beta'(s(t))\|=\displaystyle\frac{\|\alpha'(t)\|}{|s'(t)|}$, so what we need is $|s'(t)|=\|\alpha'(t)\|$, yielding to your solution.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought. The author skips **a lot** of calculations, and there's a lot of typos. I also obtained $\frac{1}{\|\alpha' \|}$ for the norm of $\alpha \circ s^{-1}$, and that's what brought me here. I'll leave the question open for a little while, and if no more opinions show up, I'll accept your answer, thank you! It was very useful!

Comment: Writing a book is not that easy.. : )

Comment: Indeed. Actually, this text was written for a mini-course given at the university I study, here. Also, english is not the native language of the author, so it is very understandable. The problem is, that are pratically no texts about this subject, focusing in differential geometry, only. Most of them focus more on the physics related to it, and in arbitrary dimensions, which is a bit too much for me right now ):